# How to change date format in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to change the date format for which I am not able to show the date in frontend.

I am using dateformat package.

```
import dateFormat from "dateformat";
const EditFinancialInfo = ({ info }) => {
  const [moneyToBePaid, setMoneyToBePaid] = useState({
    dueDate: dateFormat(info.moneyToBePaid.dueDate, "dd-MM-yyyy"),
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <input label="Due" type="date"
        name="dueDate"
        onChange={mtpHandleChange}
        value={moneyToBePaid.dueDate}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am getting this error

```
The specified value "15-30-2020" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the month of your date , the month must be from 1 to 12 that means January to december but your month is 30 , this is why this error appear

Answer (score -1):

Default format for `input type="date"` is `YYYY-MM-DD` and it is impossible to change.

You need to re-format your date value to match with input date format

```
dueDate: dateFormat(info.moneyToBePaid.dueDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```